# Why isn't YouCompleteMe working well?

Tags: vim, youcompleteme

I installed the YouCompleteMe in Vim with Vundle like this

```
Plugin 'valloric/YouCompleteMe'
```

and used

```
:PluginInstall!
```

to update the plugins in Vim, then everything was correct when I compiled YCM as the README file says:

```
cd ~/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe
./install.py --clang-completer
```

However, YCM isn't working well because every time I use the insert mode, the following prompt appears at the status line:

```
^X mode (^]^D^E^F^I^K^L^N^O^Ps^U^V^Y)
```

and no suggestion pops out. But when I comment out everything about YCM at the `.vimrc` file it doesn't happen.

How could I get around this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I solve this issue by downloading a libclang.so online, which is already clearly written at README.md of [YouCompleteMe On Github](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe).

They said clearly, that strongly recommend to download the latest version of libclang online, and compile YouCompleteMe, it will work.